# Magento 2 icons not showing on frontend

Tags: magento2

I installed a new magento 2 shop and both the front and backend were missing css etc.  I ran `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and everything looked correct except for the logo and the icon font in the front end.  I could change the logo, and the backend was showing the icons no problem.  But the front end was not rendering properly:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I missing to get these icons showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using English UK as my language.

```
\pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\fonts
```

had the missing fonts in it.  I had to copy them to

```
\pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_GB\fonts
```

I see there are a load of extra files in the en_US file, that are not in the en_GB.  No idea why this is, but copying the font files into the right place and they work.

when you install on other language let say Romanian or UK English or Spanish, the program do not download all fonts in the correct folder, so for this reason we must put them manual in the language we want .. so we can have :)

Comment: Hi, the copy to other languages should be done eitherway, in my case the copy (or the symlink creation) was broken due to some [virtualbox issues with windows symlink](https://serverfault.com/questions/476610/virtualbox-issue-with-symlinks-in-shared-folders)  
ErrMsg : Cannot create a symlink for "/.../magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/fonts/Luma-Icons.ttf" and place it to "/.../pub/static/frontend/Vendor/default/fr_FR/fonts/Luma-Icons.ttf" Warning!symlink(): Input/output error

Comment: This seems to be a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Run this commands in magento root:

```
chmod -R 0777 var; chmod -R 0777 pub/static; chmod -R 0777 pub/media; rm -Rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/;
```

This commands set the permissions and remove cache folders.
In some cases it is ok to delete the cache folders from /var

Clasic commands for clear and flush cahe is:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

And try again

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: im using xamp on local server so permissions should not be a problem.  I tried all the cache and deploys but it is not showing.  All the other media content shows - there is a specific issue with the fonts.  I have seen other people with the issue but no answers

Comment: It's for web permision not pc permision, you have a Windows, click right to folder project -> properties -> uncheck Read Only and try again.
If problem is on font, then is not ok declaration source path of font

Comment: All that does not help.  And I am not sure if your need for permissions is true - https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/setting-file-permissions-with-chmod-on-windows-for-apache-and-php

Answer (score 0):

It looks like fonts, named as "Luma-Icons.woff" and "Luma-Icons.woff2" are not getting loaded from the theme and eventually pub folder.

after setting up Symlink to Copy in di.xml

copy both fonts from vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\fonts and paste it in app\design\frontend\YourVendorName\ThemeName\web\fonts

it should work now.

Answer (score -1):

Have you guys try to replace

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

to

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

This seems to work for me.

Comment: Does not seem to be a good idea to mess with the core